# Wordpress how to assign text to the a post custom field based on the post id

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-admin

I have this code which is meant to print text to a custom field.

The code works when I manually enter the post id like this example `4221`.

However, I need to fetch the post id using `$wp_query->post->ID;`

```
//works
$post_id = '4221';
$field_key = "field_607aa2cb60022";
$value ="some tring for testing";
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );

//Dynamically, won't work
$post_id = "'$wp_query->post->ID;'";
$field_key = "field_607aa2cb60022";

$value = "some tring for testing";
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
```

I wrapped `$wp_query->post->ID;` inside single and double quotes so as to return the number in single quotes '4221'. I can't get it to work without manually specifying the post id which is something I want to avoid and just use the current post id.

Not sure how to go about it.

Additional Images
[image: Field type]

[image: Where I need to display the text]

Comment: Try and debug why is it that this isn't working. What's the value of '$wp_query->post->ID', have you tried debugging your code with xdebug, or even a var_dump($wp_query->post->ID) and then you can keep digging to find out your and fix your issue

Comment: ```$wp_query->post->ID``` outputs the post id. It doesn't work if we use it unless I supply the id like 4221 instead of ```$wp_query->post->ID```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hook it to `wp_head` action hook.

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'populating_your_custom_field');

function populating_your_custom_field(){

  $your_custom_field_value = get_field("field_607aa2cb60022");

  if (empty($your_custom_field_value)) {

    $your_custom_field_value = "My custom field text to test this";

    update_field("field_607aa2cb60022", $your_custom_field_value); 
    // Notice that you don't have to pass the id here because the default is the current post id
    // AND we used wp_head action hook. On every page load of your post, this will run
    
  }
}
```

This code would go to your `functions.php`.

Comment: I copied that into the functions file but not there yet.

Comment: As i said, you have to load your post in the frond end in order to run it. Because we hooked it to ```wp_head```.

Comment: Yes, this works! I appreciate. This sounds like a challenge :) to have to visit the frontend to load each post's value. No alternative for this bit only because the rest of the code is charm!

Comment: I have checked the data gets saved in the database without having to refresh individual posts frontend. Guess I was wrong on that one.

Comment: We could hook it to some other places but there is not enough information. For example, i don't know if it's a normal post or custom post type? Or I don't know what's the purpose of this field. When and/or where you need to run it etc.

Comment: No you don't have to constantly refresh it. Only **ONE** page load would do the trick and populate the field for you.

Comment: It's not a custom post type. I will run the code in the frontend but the reason why I needed it to display in the backend is that I am using a Yoast Custom Field Analysis plugin that detects and adds the custom fields to the total SEO score. So backend for analysis and frontend for users.

Comment: That solves it! A single refresh is all I needed. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: No problem! i'm glad that i could help!